# Ansible change string in multiple files in subfolders

Tags: ansible

I have a folder containing files as well as other folders.
I have inside those folders, some JSON files, and I would need to change in all those folders, the string "*logs*" to "*LOGINS*" in those files.

I am currently able to change this string in files that are in the main folder but was not able to change it in sub-folders.
I was also able to list all the files, even in sub-folders, but I don't know how to change the string in files which are inside a sub-folder.

Here is my current playbook:

```
- name: Find all files with extension .json under folder and all sub folders
  find:
    paths: /var/log/conf/login/
    patterns: '*.json'
    recurse: yes

- name: Replace string in files
  replace:
    dest: /var/log/conf/login/ # I have try with path instead dest but nothing cannot make is work
    regexp: 'logs'
    replace: 'LOGINS'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) module is able to give you the list of files, as you pointed it, based on this result, in order to act on this list, you will need to `register` the result of the `find` module.

```
- name: Find all files with extension .json under folder and all sub folders
  find:
    paths: /var/log/conf/login/
    patterns: '*.json'
    recurse: yes
  register: files_to_change
```

Then, with this list of files registered, you can create a loop and do the same step multiple times, on all the files resulting from the `find` module.
This would be done with the [`with_items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items) loop:

```
- name: Replace string in files
  replace:
    dest: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: 'logs'
    replace: 'LOGINS'
  with_items: "{{ files_to_change.files }}"
```

A full working playbook illustarting that would be:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    ###### 
    # Mind that this step is just there to make this example relevant, 
    # I am creating folders, as your users would do, here
    ######
    - name: Creating folders structure 
      file:
        dest: "{{ item }}"
        state: directory
      with_items:
        - /var/log/conf/login/some
        - /var/log/conf/login/sub
        - /var/log/conf/login/path/to

    ######
    # Mind that this step is just there to make this example relevant, 
    # I am just creating some JSON files, here, as your users would do
    ######
    - name: Creating file with the content to replace 
      copy:
        dest: "{{ item }}"
        content: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy logs ;)"
      with_items:
        - /var/log/conf/login/some/test.json
        - /var/log/conf/login/sub/hello.json
        - /var/log/conf/login/path/to/file.json

    - name: Find all files with extension .json under folder and all sub folders
      find:
        paths: /var/log/conf/login/
        patterns: '*.json'
        recurse: yes
      register: files_to_change

    ######
    # Mind that this is looping on the result of the find module,
    # so it is fully dynamic based on the folders that your end-users might create
    ######
    - name: Replace string in files 
      replace:
        dest: "{{ item.path }}"
        regexp: 'logs'
        replace: 'LOGINS'
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"
      with_items: "{{ files_to_change.files }}"

    - name: Display files content
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', item.path) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"
      with_items: "{{ files_to_change.files }}"
```

This would output:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Creating folders structure] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/some)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/sub)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/path/to)

TASK [Creating file with the content to replace] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/some/test.json)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/sub/hello.json)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/path/to/file.json)

TASK [Find all files with extension .json under folder and all sub folders] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Replace string in files] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/path/to/file.json)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/sub/hello.json)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/some/test.json)

TASK [Display files content] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/path/to/file.json) => {
    "msg": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy LOGINS ;)"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/sub/hello.json) => {
    "msg": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy LOGINS ;)"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=/var/log/conf/login/some/test.json) => {
    "msg": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy LOGINS ;)"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi
thanks for fast answer, my problem is that I don't know name of sub folder, this will be cretaed by other developer and can be any name, so I need to grab all file with given namy let say app-conf.json in folder and sub folde and replace string inside.
So, I need loop through folder which name I don't know.

Comment: Which is what the find is doing, yes. Have you tested it?

Comment: Just add extra-vars to your playbook for directory name once you get it from developer as below.  " ansible-playbook <playbook-name>  -e path_loc=<path_of_folder> ".  Before that, same variable you need to place it in "find" task of playook

Answer (score 0):

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "atime": 1569861712.723093,
            "ctime": 1569861712.723093,
            "dev": 104,
            "gid": 0,
            "inode": 5268,
            "isblk": false,
            "ischr": false,
            "isdir": false,
            "isfifo": false,
            "isgid": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreg": true,
            "issock": false,
            "isuid": false,
            "mode": "0755",
            "mtime": 1569861712.723093,
            "nlink": 1,
            "path": "/test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/app-config.json",
            "rgrp": true,
            "roth": true,
            "rusr": true,
            "size": 12,
            "uid": 0,
            "wgrp": false,
            "woth": false,
            "wusr": true,
            "xgrp": true,
            "xoth": true,
            "xusr": true
        },
        {
            "atime": 1569861712.7270927,
            "ctime": 1569861712.7270927,
            "dev": 104,
            "gid": 0,
            "inode": 5271,
            "isblk": false,
            "ischr": false,
            "isdir": false,
            "isfifo": false,
            "isgid": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreg": true,
            "issock": false,
            "isuid": false,
            "mode": "0755",
            "mtime": 1569861712.7270927,
            "nlink": 1,
            "path": "/test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/Test1/app-config.json",
            "rgrp": true,
            "roth": true,
            "rusr": true,
            "size": 12,
            "uid": 0,
            "wgrp": false,
            "woth": false,
            "wusr": true,
            "xgrp": true,
            "xoth": true,
            "xusr": true
        },
        {
            "atime": 1569861712.7320926,
            "ctime": 1569861712.7320926,
            "dev": 104,
            "gid": 0,
            "inode": 5274,
            "isblk": false,
            "ischr": false,
            "isdir": false,
            "isfifo": false,
            "isgid": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreg": true,
            "issock": false,
            "isuid": false,
            "mode": "0755",
            "mtime": 1569861712.7320926,
            "nlink": 1,
            "path": "/test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/Test2/app-config.json",
            "rgrp": true,
            "roth": true,
            "rusr": true,
            "size": 12,
            "uid": 0,
            "wgrp": false,
            "woth": false,
            "wusr": true,
            "xgrp": true,
            "xoth": true,
            "xusr": true
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Replace string inside file] **********************************************
failed: [localhost] (item={u'uid': 0, u'woth': False, u'mtime': 1569861712.723093, u'inode': 5268, u'isgid': False, u'size': 12, u'roth': True, u'isuid': False, u'isreg': True, u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True, u'xoth': True, u'rusr': True, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'rgrp': True, u'path': u'/test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/app-config.json', u'xusr': True, u'atime': 1569861712.723093, u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1569861712.723093, u'isblk': False, u'xgrp': True, u'dev': 104, u'wgrp': False, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0755', u'islnk': False}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"atime": 1569861712.723093, "ctime": 1569861712.723093, "dev": 104, "gid": 0, "inode": 5268, "isblk": false, "ischr": false, "isdir": false, "isfifo": false, "isgid": false, "islnk": false, "isreg": true, "issock": false, "isuid": false, "mode": "0755", "mtime": 1569861712.723093, "nlink": 1, "path": "/test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/app-config.json", "rgrp": true, "roth": true, "rusr": true, "size": 12, "uid": 0, "wgrp": false, "woth": false, "wusr": true, "xgrp": true, "xoth": true, "xusr": true}, "msg": "Destination /test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/.app-config.json does not exist !", "rc": 257}
failed: [localhost] (item={u'uid': 0, u'woth': False, u'mtime': 1569861712.7270927, u'inode': 5271, u'isgid': False, u'size': 12, u'roth': True, u'isuid': False, u'isreg': True, u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True, u'xoth': True, u'rusr': True, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'rgrp': True, u'path': u'/test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/Test1/app-config.json', u'xusr': True, u'atime': 1569861712.7270927, u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1569861712.7270927, u'isblk': False, u'xgrp': True, u'dev': 104, u'wgrp': False, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0755', u'islnk': False}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"atime": 1569861712.7270927, "ctime": 1569861712.7270927, "dev": 104, "gid": 0, "inode": 5271, "isblk": false, "ischr": false, "isdir": false, "isfifo": false, "isgid": false, "islnk": false, "isreg": true, "issock": false, "isuid": false, "mode": "0755", "mtime": 1569861712.7270927, "nlink": 1, "path": "/test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/Test1/app-config.json", "rgrp": true, "roth": true, "rusr": true, "size": 12, "uid": 0, "wgrp": false, "woth": false, "wusr": true, "xgrp": true, "xoth": true, "xusr": true}, "msg": "Destination /test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/.app-config.json does not exist !", "rc": 257}
failed: [localhost] (item={u'uid': 0, u'woth': False, u'mtime': 1569861712.7320926, u'inode': 5274, u'isgid': False, u'size': 12, u'roth': True, u'isuid': False, u'isreg': True, u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True, u'xoth': True, u'rusr': True, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'rgrp': True, u'path': u'/test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/Test2/app-config.json', u'xusr': True, u'atime': 1569861712.7320926, u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1569861712.7320926, u'isblk': False, u'xgrp': True, u'dev': 104, u'wgrp': False, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0755', u'islnk': False}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"atime": 1569861712.7320926, "ctime": 1569861712.7320926, "dev": 104, "gid": 0, "inode": 5274, "isblk": false, "ischr": false, "isdir": false, "isfifo": false, "isgid": false, "islnk": false, "isreg": true, "issock": false, "isuid": false, "mode": "0755", "mtime": 1569861712.7320926, "nlink": 1, "path": "/test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/Test2/app-config.json", "rgrp": true, "roth": true, "rusr": true, "size": 12, "uid": 0, "wgrp": false, "woth": false, "wusr": true, "xgrp": true, "xoth": true, "xusr": true}, "msg": "Destination /test/configuration/nginx/trials/Zvone/trial-admin-app/.app-config.json does not exist !", "rc": 257}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @./releases/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ansible/newtest.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=16   changed=10   unreachable=0    failed=1
```